# Unable to install openchrome driver

Tags: linux-mint, drivers, repository, video

After install needed dependencies I have follow in terminal:

> svn checkout http://svn.openchrome.org/svn/trunk openchrom
>
> svn: E170013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL
>   'http://svn.openchrome.org/svn/trunk'  svn: E670002: Unknown name or
>   service

Where I can find this driver ro install for my VIA Technology Chrome 9.

*Linux Mint 18.1 "Serena"

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to either:

- use the instructions from https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Openchrome/
- install the driver from https://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/xserver-xorg-video-openchrome